# Coveralls coverage not matching SimpleCov

Tags: ruby, simplecov, coveralls

I'm using the 'simplecov' and 'coveralls' ruby gems but the report that is generated by simplecov doesn't match the report generated by coveralls.

I've found that coveralls is not ignoring code that's wrapped in

```
# :nocov:
```

Here is my configuration

```
require "simplecov"
require "coveralls"

SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::MultiFormatter[
  SimpleCov::Formatter::HTMLFormatter,
  Coveralls::SimpleCov::Formatter
]
SimpleCov.start
```

Is there something else I need to be doing to get coveralls to ignore code?

Comment: what testing suites are you using, RSpec or Minitest? I assume the above is your test_helper content ?

Comment: I was using minitest on that project

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, I'd try the following:

1. create a *.simplecov* file on your project root folder.
2. copy your simplecov configuration in *.simplecov*.
3. Remove the Coveralls formatter from your config. So *.simplecov* now looks like this:

   `SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::HTMLFormatter`

   `SimpleCov.start`

While *test_helper.rb* looks like this:

```
require "simplecov"
require "coveralls"
```

4. Try testing again and see if the problem is fixed